# Return rows in pandas dataframe where tuple in column contains a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, dataframe

I am trying to query a pandas dataframe for rows in which one column contains a tuple containing a certain value.

As an example:

```
   User                 Col1
0     1     (cat, dog, goat)
1     1         (cat, sheep)
2     1        (sheep, goat)
3     2          (cat, lion)
4     2  (fish, goat, lemur)
5     3           (cat, dog)
6     4          (dog, goat)
7     4                  cat
```

So assuming I want to return the rows where `Col1` contains 'cat', is there a way to do this without iterating through each row and performing an "if" (my actual dataset has many more rows)?

```
df['Col1'].isin(['cat'])
```

and

```
df['Col1'].str.contains("cat")
```

only return 'true' for the last row

Answer (score 3):

You could use a lambda function within [`apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df[df["Col1"].apply(lambda x: "cat" in x)]
```

The lambda returns `True` when `"cat"` is in the cell.  That works for both strings (`"cat" in "cat"` is `True`) and tuples (`"cat" in ("cat", "dog")` is `True`).  By subsetting the `df`, you get all rows where the lambda is `True`.

Comment: You've just saved me a lot of angst. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: You could also just write `df[df["Col1"].apply(lambda x: "cat" in x)]`

Comment: You're right, @NoelEvans! Changed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not subset your data frame and then output its results?

```
catdf = df[df['Col1'].str.contains("cat")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DataFrame column contains a mixture of strings and tuples. I don't think you can avoid iterating the column. But you can iterate efficiently with the apply method. Example code follows.

```
import pandas as pd

# fake data - in a Series for simplicity
tlist = [('cat', 'dog', 'goat'),
    ('cat', 'sheep'),
    ('sheep', 'goat'),
    ('cat', 'lion'),
    ('fish', 'goat', 'lemur'),
    ('cat', 'dog'),
    ('dog', 'goat'),
    'cat']
s = pd.Series(tlist)

# iterate Series with a lambda function searching for 'cat'
s.apply(lambda x: 'cat' in x)
```

Which gave me the following output

```
Out[38]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7     True
dtype: bool
```